# Android: Intent Flag to destroy activity and start new one

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, flags

So I have a Login Activity
This Activity inflates a login.xml layout which has a USER_NAME and PASSWORD EditText Views, when I enter the Username and Password and click the Login Button I start a new Activity.

The new Activity has a Logout button which basically just starts the previous Activity like so:

```
    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Login.class);
    loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    getActivity().startActivity(loginIntent);
```

According to the Android Documentation the flag does the following:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
>
> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
> current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
> activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
> this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
> new Intent.

The problem is that the Username and Password still appear in the EditText Views after I logout, is there a Flag that destroys the Login activity and just starts a new one or is there a way to reset the fields whenever I logout? Which is the better approach?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

1 - Kill the login activity after a successful login

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Login.class);
    loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    getActivity().startActivity(loginIntent);
finish();
```

2 - Empty the values then start new activity

```
edittext_username.setText("");
edittext_password.setText("");
```

Comment: I have following flow of activity, 
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 ->
On click of button on 5th Activity , I want to go to Activity 2nd with preserving the data. So basically I want clear 3rd, 4th, 5th activity and go to 2nd with older data which is filled there earlier.
As per doc
    loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
is not working.

Please help me, I'm really stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 5):

If you are supporting only API levels 11+, you should be able to use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK). This will finish all existing Activities in all tasks and create a new instance of the Login activity.

Comment: I tried that flag but it didn't finish or destroy the Login activity, it seems like it just brought it to the front.

Comment: Interesting. According to the documentation, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP should finish and recreate the activity as well (so long as you are not using FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in conjunction with it and your launch mode is the default "multiple")