# How to clear current activity stack when start another activity which belong to another stack

Tags: android, activity-stack

For example:A start B, B start C, A and C belongs to 'Hello'-stack, and B belongs to 'World'-stack, when user press back button in Activity C, it will return to A.
Note1:B means a lot of activities , not just one activity,
like A start B1,B1 start B2, B2 start B3....,Bn start C. 
Note2:I need Bs remain in stack until C has been launched , when user press
back in B3, it should return to b2.
[image]

I actually have implemented this need by using startActivityForResult,and I just want to know is there any way using stack to implements this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798737/android-intent-flag-to-destroy-activity-and-start-new-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
or 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call finish() when you start Activity C from B.
Then override onBackPressed() in activity C. And add code to start Activity A.

Comment: sorry, i did not describe my question clearly..there is more than one activity in 'World'-stack  in top of B.

Comment: Clearly tell flow of activities

Comment: Yeah.. Whenever you call a new activity, just destroy the present activity by calling finish() after startActivity(). On Activity C, Override onBackPressed() method. In the method, start activity A..

Comment: Simply call Intent in=new Intent(ActivityC.this,ActivityA.class);
 startActivity(in); in onBackPressed() method of ActivityC. Thats it.

Comment: Hey @empty-yo.. your question is clossed ah? I mean your problem is solved or not? If yes, mark my answer as accepted, else reply with your queries. Otherwise this question will be in pending status.

Answer (score 0):

When going from activity A to activity B, go as below:

```
 Intent i=new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

And as you want to open C from B but don't want B to be in stack, so do as below:

```
 Intent i=new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityC.class);
 startActivity(i);
 ActivityB.this.finish();
```

So automatically when backpressed on C, you will get A and not B.